# Python 3 Import Error no module named urllib3

Tags: pip, python-3.6, urllib

I wrote a script to do some IP address analysis from an imported CSV and it will not run with urllib3.  I have tired uninstalling and reinstalling the module and even set up an new virtualenv. I get the following error message despite the module being shown below as imported:

````
(ENV) foo@Servername:~$ sudo python IP_Analysis_CSV.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "IP_Analysis_CSV.py", line 4, in <module>
    import urllib3
ImportError: No module named urllib3

(ENV) foo@Servername:~$ pip freeze
certifi==2019.9.11
chardet==3.0.4
DateTime==4.3
idna==2.8
pytz==2019.3
requests==2.22.0
urllib3==1.25.6
zope.interface==4.6.0```
````

Comment: Why are you using `sudo`?

Comment: It gives me a `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/mnt/otherserver/IPfile_20191010.csv'` issue.  Have to use elevated privileges to access that file.

Comment: Then use your elevated privileges just to grant your user read access on the file (or a copy of it).  Don't run the entire Python runtime under root!  This is also the cause of your issue, since `pip` is invoking the python runtime for your user, but `sudo python` is root's environment.

Comment: That works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to wim:

Running the script as sudo invokes the root python runtime where urllib3 is not installed.  Where as running under your normal user account invokes the runtime where urllib3 is installed.